# have trouble understanding angularjs components. Only used directives before

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

So I've been using one controller one view, and using only Directives for parts that I want to use repeatedly.

Now Im going for an interview and I am asked to learn about component, which I never know existed. I'm trying to replace directive with it but can't even pass a simple object into the component from the parent controller.

1. (first question) I've been using $scope for everything. Now that I'm reading on component, I see $ctrl used everywhere, what's the different?

**app.js**

```
var myApp= angular.module('bigMoveApp', ['ngRoute', 'testerModule']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.

    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/Views/main.html',
        controller: 'ctrlMain'
    }).

    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

**ctrlMain.js**

```
myApp.controller('ctrlMain', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 //code
     $scope.paragraphToWrite = { text: "let's write something" };
 //code
}])
```

**main.html**

```
<div id="main-body-wrapper">
<...>
    <paragraph-Component obj="paragraphToWrite"></paragraph-Component>
 <...>
</div>
```

**paragraphComponent.js**

```
    function paragraphController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.user = $scope.$parent.textFields.whatWeDo.title;
        var x = ctrl.obj;
    } 


    myApp.component('paragraphComponent', {
        templateUrl: '/app/Views/paragraphCom.html',
        bindings: {
            obj : '='
        },  
        controller: paragraphController 
    })
```

2. (second question), what am I doing wrong here, I cant even pass in a simple object to the component

Please help, I need to wrap my head around component before end of today, I've been reading on this for the whole night yesterday and still don't quite grasp it. I don't even understand the benefit of component, when directive can do more from my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, its nothing new. AngularJS component API is [**just a wrapper around a directive API**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1637-L1695). Behind the scenes it create a directive when you use `.component` API. These change has been introduced to make a migration of AngularJS to Angular(2+) version smoother. Also API readability will also looks similar as Angular is totally based on `component`.

Coming back to your questions

1. Whenever you use `controllerAs` pattern while defining a controller, all the binding value resides inside your `$scope.controllerAlias` variable. Eventually if you see whats there in alias, you will see that `this`(context) is exactly populated over there. There you shouldn't be using `$scope` inside a controller, rather everthing will be resides inside you controller function `this`, which is nothing but `$ctrl` default controller alias.
2. You had typo while using your component name. `paragraph-Component` tag should be `paragraph-component`

   ```
   <paragraph-component obj="paragraphToWrite"></paragraph-component>
   ```

Comment: Thanks! that make a lot of sense now. 
As for number 2, I fixed the typo but under `paragraphComponent.js` at the `var x = ctrl.obj` line, it is still showing undefined.

Comment: oh nvm I found out why now. Turns out I tried to get the value too quickly, the controller binding is not even done yet. I solved it with `$onInit`. damn wasted so much time on this. Thanks man!